# What permission give me access to code branches in Azure DevOps?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I don't see the Branches link in Azure DevOps in the Repos menu:

[image]

The Azure admin has confirmed that I'm in the Contributor group and I can access branches through Visual Studio Team Services.

I haven't been able to find the setting that will let me manage branches in Azure DevOps / visualstudio.com.

---

ANSWER:

So dumb... I needed to change this dropdown from the TFVC project in the Azure DevOps header:

[image]

To the Git repo:

[image]

And now I see options for Branches and Pull Requests in my Repos sub-menu:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot,seems you are using TFVC as your source control. **This is the expected behavior.**

For **TFVC** project the option under Repos should be

[image]

For **Git** project the option under Repos should be

[image]

You could do some manages in Visual Studio from Source Control Explorer.

[image]

Or use [tf branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/branch-command?view=azure-devops) command line to handle this.

Comment: I'm definitely using Git as my source control plug-in in Visual Studio. I've been commiting code to my branch and merging branches using GitHub desktop.

When I go View => Other Windows => the Source Control Explorer link is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The branches menu looks to only be available when you are using Git as your source control system.  When you are using TFVC that option is not available.  The actual branches are shown under the repository menu structure.  It appears you will probably have to use Visual Studio for the branch operations.

[image]

Comment: The repositories are definitely Git repositories. My VS source control plugin is Git. And I've been committing code and merging branches in GitHub desktop. The problem now is that I need to make a Pull Request, but in my VS Team Explorer, I don't see a Pull Requests link / button on the Home tab and in GitHub desktop, the "Create Pull Request" link is disabled.